# Prevent full screen div on viewport overlaps contents below it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem dealing with Foundation 6's Orbit. I set the orbit became full screen on viewport (browser window). I opened my browser's developer tools and I saw the orbit overlapped the headings below (Try to resize the developer tools/Codepen's console). I don't know if this is a bug or not. Please take a look at https://codepen.io/billyhalim/pen/zwbPdV.

[image: screenshot of Codepen]

HTML

```
<div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Slideshow" data-orbit data-options="animInFromLeft:fade-in; animInFromRight:fade-in; animOutToLeft:fade-out; animOutToRight:fade-out;">
      <ul class="orbit-container">
        <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
        <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
        <li class="is-active orbit-slide bg1"></li>
        <li class="orbit-slide bg2"></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

CSS

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.orbit, .orbit-container, .orbit-slide{
    height: 100%;
}

.orbit-slide.bg1{
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3OF7s7u97QM/VeaBIMsZEBI/AAAAAAAACJo/Uy8rmeqdNDg/s1600/Gambar-Konyol-Lucu-Gila-Unik-Aneh-14.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

.orbit-slide.bg2{
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9izs08OyhuU/VeaBPrheKHI/AAAAAAAACMQ/uUN7ELsMw_o/s1600/Gambar-Konyol-Lucu-Gila-Unik-Aneh-34.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

I also face another problems. Sometimes, the height of the orbit slider was cut off and when I refreshed the page the height became normal. A blank/white slide sometimes appeared too and refreshing the page was to get back normal. I don't know if this is the Foundation's Orbit bug or my browser's rendering problems. I would to get some solutions for these.

Thank you.

Comment: overlap? that's the console causing it, turn off the console, should be good?

Comment: I don't see any issue on codepen.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, but if I use 100vh, the orbit doesn't overlap the contents below. I feel I need to know this problem? Why does it happen? The same thing if you open your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @j-printemps Try to open your browser's developer tools and resize it vertically, you won't see the "Hello" contents below.